# unix tools to parse file on the command line

Tags: python, unix, command-line-tool, command-line-arguments

I have a python script that looks like the following that I want to transform:

```
import sys
# more imports


''' some comments '''

class Foo:
   def _helper1():
      etc.

   def _helper2():
      etc.

   def foo1():
      d = { a:3, b:2, c:4 }
      etc.

   def foo2():
      d = { a:2, b:2, c:7 }
      etc.

   def foo3():
      d = { a:3, b:2, c:7 }
      etc.

   etc.

   if __name__ == "__main__":    
      etc.
```

I'd like to be able to parse JUST the `foo*()` functions and keep just the ones that have certain attributes, like `d={a:3, b:2}`. Obviously keep everything else that is non `foo*()` so the transformation will still run.  The `foo*()` will be well defined though `d` may have different key, values.

Is there some set of unix tools I can use to do this through chaining?  I can use `grep` to identify `foo` but how would I scan the next couple of lines to apply the keep or reject portion of my logic?

edit: note, i'm trying to see if it's reasonable to do this with command line tools before writing a custom parser.  i know how to write the parser.

Comment: There are tools built into python for manipulating python, that's going to work much more reliably than trying to regex your way into an ad-hoc python parser.

Comment: Hello. Your question is off-topic and will likely be closed soon. I recommend that you complete our [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read our [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to understand what is on-topic for this site.

Comment: There's been a lot of comments on hackernews about how militant SO has become and the above comment punctuates this.  Not sure why this is considered off topic as I'm trying to reuse existing tools before writing a custom parser.  As unix has dozens of commandline tools, it's valid not to expect people to know all of them...

Comment: It's more of a tool suggestion question than a programming question. But to answer your question, have a look at sed and awk. That said, @pvg is absolutely right; you should use the tools built into the python standard library for this.

Comment: The site docs explain very clearly why such questions are off-topic. Take a look at [help/on-topic]

Comment: What specifically are you you guys looking at b/c the 5th line down in your link reads:

but if your question generally covers…

software tools commonly used by programmers; and is

… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: You really ought to read the whole thing. "Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above: [...] Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: There are tags called "command-line-tool" and "command-line-parsing".

Comment: The fact that there are such tags doesn't make your question on-topic. I'm not sure why you're so interested in arguing about this instead of fixing your question so you can get some help. 'I tried to parse X with tool Y doing Z, got this error, expected such and such instead' - that's an on-topic question that might fit those tags. 'What's the best tool to parse X on the command line' is an off-topic question. It's super-simple.

Comment: added an edit.  didn't ask for best tool.  people are too quick to jump on people here and flash the rule books (again, I'm not the only one saying this).  chill out and give people the benefit of the doubt (even if they don't have a lot of karma points).

Comment: The rules are there for a reason. You can try to find a site with different rules. Or you can ask questions that fit the rules. Or you can go on meta and debate the rules if you want. But nobody is treating you poorly, you just don't like the rules. That's fine, but they are what they are.

Comment: hm.. pointed to the exact line in a rules link you sent that contradicts your statement and somehow I'm being defensive?  got it.  honestly, your first comment should have been an answer to get your points.  continue to argue if you must.  i'm done on this thread.

Comment: It doesn't contradict it, in fact, it's clarified right there, you just appear to not have read it the first time and not to have read it the second time when posted verbatim. You're going to have a much easier and less frustrating time if you take a few minutes to read that stuff.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't specified your problem with enough detail to recommend a particular solution, but there are many tools and techniques that will handle this type of problem.

As I understand this, you want to

1. Identify the boundaries of your class
2. Identify the methods within the class
3. Remove the methods lacking certain textual features

My general approach to this would be a script with logic based on "open old and new files; write everything you read from the old file, unless ."

You can blithely write things until you get into the class (one flag) and start finding methods (another flag).  The one slightly tricky part here is the buffering: you need to keep the text of each method until you know whether it contains the target text.  You can either read in the entire method (minor parsing task) and search that for the target, or simply hold lines of text until you find the target (then return to your write-it-all mode) or run off the end (empty the buffer without writing).

This is simply enough that you could cobble a script in any handy language to handle the problem.  UNIX provides a variety of tools; in *that* paradigm I'd use **awk**.  However, I recommend a read-friendly tool, such as Python or Perl.  If you want to move formally into the world of parsing, I suggest a trivial Lex-YACC couplet: you can have very simple tokens (perhaps even complete lines, depending on your coding style) and actions (write line, hold line, set status flag, flush buffer, etc.).

Is that enough to get you moving?

Comment: ok thanks.  yeah, i know how to write a custom parser (and I should have mentioned this), was just wondering if there were some command line tools I could use to do this before writing code.

Comment: Nothing so simple as a command-line filter.  **awk** might be the most direct solution, but unless you already know the pattern=>action syntax, it won't be your most effective solution.